# Should dataclass use fields for attributes with only defaults?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

When a python `dataclass` has a simple attribute that only needs a default value, it can be defined either of these ways.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass
class ExampleClass:
    x: int = 5  

@dataclass
class AnotherClass:
    x: int = field(default=5)
```

I don't see any advantage of one or the other in terms of functionality, and so would go with the less verbose version.  Of course field offers other bells and whistles, but I don't need them yet and could easily refactor to use `field` later.

Is there any advantage to using `field` for a simple default over just a type hint?

Comment: According to ChatGPT, which I take with a grain of salt, "In most cases, if your goal is simply to provide a default value for an attribute and you don't need to customize or access properties of the field(), using the simpler syntax without field() is perfectly fine and more concise."

Comment: Part of the point of dataclass is to have a streamlined way of defining things, one which takes advantage of type annotations. So use the simpler form. `field` exists to provide features which can't be done via simple syntax alone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if all you need is a field with a default value and no other special behavior, assigning the value directly to the class variable is equivalent to a `field` with only a `default` parameter.

```
x: int = field(default=5)
x: int = 5
```

In fact, Python goes way out of its way to make sure the two behave equivalently. From [PEP 557](https://peps.python.org/pep-0557/),

> If the default value of a field is specified by a call to `field()`, then the class attribute for this field will be replaced by the specified `default` value. If no `default` is provided, then the class attribute will be deleted. The intent is that after the `dataclass` decorator runs, the class attributes will all contain the default values for the fields, just as if the default value itself were specified.

So whether or not you assign a `field`, at runtime, the value of both of the `x`'s above on the *class* (as opposed to an instance) will be the number `5`.

For the sake of completeness, the reasons you would *want* to call `field` rather than writing simply a type annotation include:

- Providing a `default_factory`, which is a callable that runs every time an instance is constructed (i.e. `x: list = []` will be the same list every time, whereas `x: list = field(default_factory=list)` will be a new list for each instance)
- Removing the field from the parameters from consideration in some or all of the dataclass-generated functionality. You can remove the field from `__init__` params, from the printed `__repr__`, from the comparison method, and from the generated `__hash__`.
- Adding third party `metadata`. This doesn't affect `dataclasses` but can be used to share arbitrary information about a dataclass field with a third party library.

If none of the above apply to you, stick to the simple syntax and don't call `field`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no advantage of using field in this case, the effect will be the same.

Internally, dataclass code will capture the value you passed to `default=` in `field` and assigns it to the attribute, as if you had initialized normally in the class ([see](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/dataclasses.py#L884)).

So, stick to:

```
@dataclass
class ExampleClass:
    x: int = 5
```